# Closed form for numbers $428$, $4288$, $42888$,...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Closed form for numbers $428$, $4288$, $42888$,...

I search a closed form for numbers of this form

$4288=428+386\cdot 10$

$42888=4288+386\cdot 10^2$

$\cdot \cdot\cdot $

Is the right way to find a closed form?

Answer (score 3):

The number begins with $42$ and then followed by $8$.

$$a_n = 42\cdot 10^{1+n}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 8(10)^i= 42\cdot 10^{1+n}+\frac89(10^n-1)$$

Answer (score 3):

Write

$$n_{k+1}=10n_k+8$$

and solve the recurrence.

If you temporarily drop the constant term,

$$n_{k+1}=10n_k$$ has the easy solution $$n_k=c\,10^k.$$

Then for the constant term, assume a constant solution, let $d$.

$$d=10d+8$$ yields

$$d=-\frac89.$$

Now we combine* as

$$n_k=c\,10^k-\frac89.$$

If $n_0=42$, then $c=42+\dfrac89$

and

$$n_k=\frac{386\cdot10^k-8}{9}.$$

---

*This is justified by the fact that the recurrence is linear. If you find two solutions for equations with different RHS, the solution for the sum of the RHS is the sum of the respective solutions.

Comment: perfect solution!

Comment: @user912664: I posted a second solution, which I think better.

Comment: @user912664: does this lead you to a correct solution ?

Comment: yes it is correct, I do not understant d=10d+8 for the constant term

Comment: @user912664: $n_k=d$ for all $k$.

Comment: ok now I understand...yes infact $n_k-10\cdot n_k=8$, for all k, is it right? and this is equivalent to $d-10\cdot d=8$, isnt' it?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

A growing number of $8$'s reminds us of the fraction $\dfrac89$. Let us observe what happens when we multiply all these numbers by $9$:

$$3852,38592,385992,3859992,\cdots$$
or

$$3860-8,38600-8,386000-8,3860000-8,\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, just a remark: you've been presented with many completely valid solutions, but your own approach was actually ok. First notice
$$
428 = 42+386\cdot 10^0
$$
Then, notice that
$$ \begin{aligned}
42888 &= 4288+386\cdot 10^2 \\
&= (428+386\cdot 10^1)+386\cdot 10^2 \\
&= (42+386\cdot 10^0)+386\cdot 10^1+386\cdot 10^2 \\
&= 42+386\cdot (10^0+10^1+10^2)
\end{aligned}$$
Now, remembering that $x^0+x^1+\ldots+x^n=\dfrac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$ you easily arrive at the closed form:
$$
42+386\frac{10^{n+1}-1}{10-1}
$$